# How do I make a horizontal slider in a table without moving text?

Tags: vuetify.js

Please help me with the tables in vuetify.
I need to limit the width of the table, and remove text wrapping. I need a horizontal slider.
[codepen](https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/eYpzMzg)

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1 max-width-test"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>

.max-width-test{
  max-width: 900px
}
```

Comment: Very hard to understand your issue. This article related? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_responsive.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The css method helped me: white-space: nowrap;
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Meller008/pen/eYpzMzg)

```
.max-width-test{
  max-width: 900px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```